# Oracle Apex PDF Viewer

Tags: oracle, pdf, oracle-apex

i am new in Oracle-Apex. I need Help to show a PDF in Oracle APEX. I have a question: I have uploaded the PDF in to the Database. I save the PDF as a blob in database. After that i showed the name of the PDF in Classic Report.When i click on the name, i want to see the preview of the PDF that i had uploaded. 
 Now i am searching a way to show the PDF with a Code. Can somebody help?

I need previous and next button.

How can i show this PDF in the Region?[here is my Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbKLB.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example I quickly whipped up using `APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES`. Hopefully it's what you're trying to achieve.
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=34781

> Username: demo
>   Password: demo

This uses the [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) project by Mozilla. Here's a quick recipe of what you may need.

1. Create a `File Browse` page item and set the Storage Type to `Table APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES`.
2. Create a page button to submit the page.
3. Create a Classic Report region and enter the following query:

   ```
   select
       id
       , filename
   from apex_application_temp_files
   where application_id = :APP_ID
   ```
4. Add a virtual column and set the HTML Expression:

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn-preview-pdf" data-id="#ID#">Preview</button>
   ```
5. Create a region and enter the following in the Source:

   ```
   <canvas id="preview-pane"></canvas>
   ```
6. Create a Click dynamic action.

   a. Set the selection Type to `jQuery Selector`.

   b. Enter the jQuery Selector `.btn-preview-pdf`.
7. Add a `Execute JavaScript Code` action with the following JS code (check out the examples from the PDF.js website for more details on what the code does):

   ```
   var fileId = $(this.triggeringElement).data('id');
   var docUrl = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=DOWNLOADPDF:::FILE_ID:' + fileId;
   var previewPane = this.affectedElements[0];

   // from PDF.js examples
   pdfjsLib.getDocument(docUrl).then(function(pdf) {
       var pageNumber = 1;
       pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
           console.log('Page loaded');

           var scale = 1.5;
           var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

           // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
           var canvas = previewPane;
           var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
           canvas.height = viewport.height;
           canvas.width = viewport.width;

           // Render PDF page into canvas context
           var renderContext = {
               canvasContext: context,
               viewport: viewport
           };
           var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
           renderTask.then(function () {
               console.log('Page rendered');
           });
       })
   }, function(reason) {
       console.error(reason);
   });
   ```
8. For the action, also set the Affected Elements:

   a. Selection Type: `jQuery Selector`

   b. jQuery Selector: `#preview-pane`
9. Follow Joel Kallman's [post](https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2014/03/yet-another-post-how-to-link-to.html) on creating a link to download a file. You will need an Application Process (`DOWNLOADPDF`) and an Application Item (`FILE_ID`) The modified code for the Application Process `DOWNLOADPDF` looks like this:

   ```
   begin
       for file in (select *
                   from apex_application_temp_files
                   where id = :FILE_ID) loop
           --
           sys.htp.init;
           sys.owa_util.mime_header( file.mime_type, FALSE );
           sys.htp.p('Content-length: ' || sys.dbms_lob.getlength( file.blob_content));
           sys.htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || file.filename || '"' );
           sys.htp.p('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');  -- tell the browser to cache for one hour, adjust as necessary
           sys.owa_util.http_header_close;
           sys.wpg_docload.download_file( file.blob_content );

           apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
       end loop;
   end;
   ```
10. Almost missed this out. On the Page Attributes, set the JavaScript File URLs to any of the CDNs [listed](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/). For example:

    //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.550/pdf.min.js

Note that this is a very basic prototype. The preview only allows you to view the first page. You will need to figure out the [API](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/index.html) and then do the necessary to allow multipage viewing. I'll leave you to figure that out.

That should be it. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: It's work! Thanks man, You saved my life. How can i change to multipage viewing ?

Comment: I have updated the demo to show case pagination. It's a crude solution. I will update the post another time with details. Meanwhile, take a look at the new buttons and the JavaScript. As mention, the trick is in the page rendering function and the page number parameter that it takes. It will benefit you to think of how to use this on your own.

Comment: I saw Demo. It's cool. I need only Prev. und next button. Can you send me details? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the next and previous buttons code please, thank you @Adrian P